# Working With OneToOne/Foreign Fields

Tags: python, django

I've been struggling with this all week long, and I need to put it to rest once and for all. This might look like a lot of code, but at the core is a simple conceptual question.

I have a model, UserProfile, that has the following fields:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
weekOne = models.OneToOneField(WeekOne)
weekTwo = models.OneToOneField(WeekTwo)
```

WeekOne and WeekTwo are both models with their own unique fields (models.Model) that inherit from a custom class called Week. Week just has a few custom functions to save some re-typing of methods for each week and the following code to make it an abstract class:

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Basically, I want every user to have a unique weekOne and weekTwo (and beyond) field that has custom fields with values that are unique to the user.

When I first create a user (i.e., when they sign up), I use the following code in `views.py`:

```
def signup(request):
    user_form = UserCreateForm(data=request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if user_form.is_valid():
            username = user_form.clean_username()
            password = user_form.clean_password2()
            user_form.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return index(request, user_form=user_form)
    return redirect('/')
```

Basic form signup stuff, everything has always worked fine here.

Now, here's where things get dicey. I have a view for weekOne that makes sure a user's profile has been created and creates one if not, the code for which is as follows:

```
@login_required
def workout1(request):
    template = "workout1.html"
    weekOne = WeekOne()
    weekOne.save()
    user, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user,
            defaults = {'weekOne': weekOne})
    name = weekOne.__unicode__()

    if created:
        context = {'user': user}
        return render(request, template, context)

    # Grab already existing User Profile
    weekOne.delete() # Was never used
    context = {'user': user, 'name': name}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Okay. So that's cool. But when I try to go to the page for week one, I get the following error:

```
workout_game_app_userprofile.weekTwo_id may not be NULL
```

This is where I'm lost. Should I be initializing every single week variable for every single week view? I.e., for the week one view, should I be doing code like this:

```
weekOne = WeekOne()
weekTwo = WeekTwo()
weekThree = WeekThree()
```

etc.? This seems absurdly repetitive if I have to do it for all 12 weeks I'm planning on implementing.

Btw, my models were functioning perfectly well before I implemented the second week.

Also, is OneToOne the right kind of key to use? I want to do things like access user.weekOne.item1, user.weekOne.item2, etc. and change and save their values only for that user.

`UPDATE`: For Sidharth Shah, here's the rest of the code from my views and models:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from workout_game_app.forms import AuthenticateForm, UserCreateForm
from workout_game_app.models import WeekOne, WeekTwo, UserProfile
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.core import serializers
import simplejson


def index(request, auth_form=None, user_form=None):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        name = "Missions Overview"
        context = {'user': user, 'name': name}
        template = 'workouts.html'
        return render(request, template, context)
    else:
        auth_form = auth_form or AuthenticateForm()
        user_form = user_form or UserCreateForm()
        template = 'index.html'
        context = {'auth_form': auth_form, 'user_form': user_form}
        return render(request, template, context)

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticateForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            login(request, form.get_user())
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return index(request, auth_form=form)
    return redirect('/')


def signup(request):
    user_form = UserCreateForm(data=request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if user_form.is_valid():
            username = user_form.clean_username()
            password = user_form.clean_password2()
            user_form.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return index(request, user_form=user_form)
    return redirect('/')

@login_required
def submitWorkout1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        exercise = request.POST['exercise']
        try:
            amount = request.POST['amount']
        except KeyError: # No amount field on form
            amount = ""
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        week = user.weekOne
        exercise, amount, exerciseComplete, allComplete = user.updateExercise(week, exercise, amount)
        data = simplejson.dumps({
            'result': 'success',
            'exercise': exercise,
            'amount': amount,
            'exerciseComplete': exerciseComplete,
            'allComplete': allComplete
            }, indent=4)
        return HttpResponse(data)


@login_required
def workout2(request):
    template = "workout2.html"
    weekTwo = WeekTwo()
    weekTwo.save()
    user, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user,
            defaults = {'weekTwo': weekTwo})
    name = weekTwo.__unicode__()

    if created:
        context = {'user': user}
        return render(request, template, context)

    # Grab already existing User Profile
    weekTwo.delete() # Was never used
    context = {'user': user, 'name': name}
    return render(request, template, context)

@login_required
def submitWorkout2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        exercise = request.POST['exercise']
        try:
            amount = request.POST['amount']
        except KeyError: # No amount field on form
            amount = ""
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        week = user.weekTwo
        exercise, amount, exerciseComplete, allComplete = user.updateExercise(week, exercise, amount)
        data = simplejson.dumps({
            'result': 'success',
            'exercise': exercise,
            'amount': amount,
            'exerciseComplete': exerciseComplete,
            'allComplete': allComplete
            }, indent=4)
        return HttpResponse(data)
```

and models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Week(models.Model):
    # List of exercises by name for the week
    exercises = []
    # Week name in unicode
    name = u''

    # Running count of benchmarks met.
    completeCount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    # Set to true if benchmarks reached. 
    weekComplete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        # A bunch of methods

class WeekOne(Week):
    name = u'Mission One'
    exercises = ['squats', 'lunges', 'stairDaysCount', 'skipStairs']
    # Required benchmarks for given exercises
    squatBenchmark = 1000
    lungeBenchmark = 250
    stairDaysCountBenchmark = 3

    totalGoals = 4

    squats = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    lunges = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    skipStairs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stairDaysCount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    # A bunch of methods

class WeekTwo(Week):
    name = u'Mission Two'
    exercises = ['up3Levels', 'noHands', 'treadmill', 'vagMachine', 'extendedStairs']
    totalGoals = 5

    up3Levels = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    noHands = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    treadmill = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vagMachine = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    extendedStairs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # A bunch of methods

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    weekOne = models.OneToOneField(WeekOne, null=True, default=None)
    weekTwo = models.OneToOneField(WeekTwo, null=True, default=None)
    # Some methods
```

and, though it works fine, my forms.py for good measure:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True,
            widget = forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(required=True,
            widget = forms.widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True,
            widget = forms.widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))

    def is_valid(self):
        form = super(UserCreateForm, self).is_valid()
        for f, error in self.errors.iteritems():
            if f != '__all_':
                self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class':'error', 'value':strip_tags(error)})
        return form

    class Meta:
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']
        model = User

class AuthenticateForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Username'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have following model

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
weekOne = models.OneToOneField(WeekOne, null=True, default=None)
weekTwo = models.OneToOneField(WeekTwo, null=True, default=None)
```

Try that out, it should work. Looking at the code above you're defining fields weekOne, weekTwo etc. What I am not sure of is if you're assigning all necessary fields weekOne object while creating it.

Comment: Weirdly when I try to do that I get this error after trying to update my databases: `DatabaseError: table "workout_game_app_weekone" already exists`. I'm just dealing with test data so I deleted my entire database first using the `flush` command and then just straight up deleting the database file -- still getting the error. As for the fields in WeekOne and WeekTwo, all of them have default values.

Comment: This is the perfect usecase of why you should be using something like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/). It takes care of you db migrations. If you don't mind can you please share your code, I can clone and take a look at whats going on?

Comment: That's the worst part -- I AM using South. I've updated my post with the entirety of my views, models, and forms at the bottom.